# Form is not showing for the first row but showing for the other rows in laravel 8

Tags: laravel-8

Please help me for this issue.
The Problem is form tag is not showing for the first row but showing for the other rows in laravel 8.
Here my blade template code...

```
  @foreach($products as $product)
      <tr>
        <form method="post" id="{{$product->product_code}}" action="{{url('/add-cart')}}">
           @csrf
        </form>
        <input type="hidden" form="{{$product->product_code}}" value="{{$product->id}}" name="id">
        <input type="hidden" form="{{$product->product_code}}" value="{{$product->product_name}}" name="name">
        <input type="hidden" form="{{$product->product_code}}" value="1" name="qty">
        <input type="hidden" form="{{$product->product_code}}" value="{{$product->product_price}}" name="price">
        <td>{{$product->product_name}}</td>
        <td>{{$product->product_price}}</td>
        <td>{{$product->product_code}}</td>
        <td> <button type="submit" form="{{$product->product_code}}" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" data-id="{{$product->id}}"><i class="fas fa-plus-square" style="font-size: 20px;"></i></button></td>
     </tr>
                                                      
    @endforeach
```

Please see my output code in inspect element view :
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Its solved .

I just use empty form tag before main form tag inside foreach loop, then first empty form tag is removed by foreach loop and functionality is working fine:

```
@foreach($products as $product)
  <tr>
    <form></form>
    <form method="post" id="{{$product->product_code}}" action="{{url('/add-cart')}}">
       @csrf
    </form>
    <input type="hidden" form="{{$product->product_code}}" value="{{$product->id}}" name="id">
    <input type="hidden" form="{{$product->product_code}}" value="{{$product->product_name}}" name="name">
    <input type="hidden" form="{{$product->product_code}}" value="1" name="qty">
    <input type="hidden" form="{{$product->product_code}}" value="{{$product->product_price}}" name="price">
    <td>{{$product->product_name}}</td>
    <td>{{$product->product_price}}</td>
    <td>{{$product->product_code}}</td>
    <td> <button type="submit" form="{{$product->product_code}}" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" data-id="{{$product->id}}"><i class="fas fa-plus-square" style="font-size: 20px;"></i></button></td>
 </tr>
                                                  
@endforeach
```